# Функция умножения float чисел

Tags: c++, функции

Пытаюсь написать функцию с переменным числом параметров без использования доп библиотек.
Функция такого вида: sum(int к-во элементов,элемент1,элемент2 и тд)
Уже битый час пытаюсь заставить мою функцию считать float числа, но тщетно.
Что я делаю не так?

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <conio.h>
    float sum (int n, float,...)
    {  int *p = &n; float s = 1;
       for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
         s*= *(++p);
        return s;
    }
    void main()
    {  std::cout << sum(3,2.2,2.1,2.5);
getch();
     }
```

На выходе получаю float числа в огромных степенях.

Comment: Интересно, почему функция **умножения** имеет имя **`sum`**?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все правильно делаете, не учли только одного: вещественные константы по умолчанию имеют тип double (8 байт), а не float (4 байта), из-за чего значения считываются из стека некорректно (точнее, помещается туда не то, что ожидается). Вот правильный вызов и немного откорректированный вариант:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

float sum (int n, float,...)
{  
  float *p = (float *)&n;
  float s = 1;

  while (n--)
    s *= *++p;
  return s;
}

int main()
{  
  std::cout << sum(3,2.2f,2.1f,2.5f);
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Запускаем и получаем:

```
-8.855
```

Что только кажется правильным. В результате из двух ответов собираем один - и способ имеет право на существование (в учебных целях), и @AnT прав насчет double. Получаем такой вариант:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

double sum (int n, double,...)
{  
  double *p = (double *)(&n+1);
  double s = 1;

  while (n--)
    s *= *p++;
  return s;
}

int main()
{  
  std::cout << sum(3,2.2,2.1,2.5);
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

И правильный вывод `11.55`

Comment: Запускаем. Получаем `0`. И что же тут правильного? "Правильным" это не может быть в принципе, ибо как я уже говорил, `float` значения никогда в качестве variadic параметров не передаются. То , что вы указали суффикс `f` в аргументах дела не меняет - передаются все равно `double` параметры.

Comment: @AnT, в чем запускаете? Обновил ответ.

Comment: Это **категорически** неправильно, так как правильный путь описан в стандарте - `va_list` и соответствующие макросы.

Comment: Что ж делать, если преподаватель требует такое решение, основанное на его знании о том, как параметры помещаются в стек? Может хочет, чтобы студенты знали что прячется внутри? Что касается практического программирования, то абсолютно согласен, что надо пользоваться стандартными средствами. Ответ обновил.

Comment: Что делать? Ну, мне кажется, что написать тогда уж по крайней мере так: правильно - вот так и только так. Для идиота, который требует делать неправильно - сделайте вот так, только забудьте этот способ немедленно по сдаче этого кода!...

Comment: В том и проблема. Поддерживаю!

Comment: Возможно, они там действительно в Borland C 3.1 пишут...

Answer (score 6):

Во-первых, доступ к variadic параметрам в С и С++ делатся через макросы группы `va_list/va_start/va_arg`. Никаким другим способом этот доступ осуществить нельзя. Откуда вы взяли вот эту манеру доступа через `int *p = &n;` - мне не ясно.

Во-вторых, при передаче `float` значений через variadic параметры, они всегда неявно преобразуются к значениям типа `double`. Поэтому никакого `float` внутри функции тут не может быть в принципе.

В-третиьх, значения вида `2.2`, `2.5` и т.п. - это уже `double`, то есть никакого `float` вы даже и не пытаетесь передавать.

Поэтому доступ тут делается только и именно через `va_arg(..., double)`.

Comment: В методичке ВУЗа был следующий код для суммы int элементов:

`#include <iostream>
int sum (int n, ...)
{  int *p = &n; int s = 0;
   for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
     s+= *(++p);
    return s;    
}
void main()
{  std::cout << sum(6,4,5,1,2,3,0); 
 }` , а условие - 
2. Написать функцию с переменным числом параметров, которая находит произведение чисел типа float.

Comment: @John Doe: Такую методичку вы можете смело выбрасывать в топку. `void main`... (Вздыхаю...)

Comment: Ну что поделать, как учат так учат, надежда на самого себя в будущем только. Сегодня сдача последней лабораторной - этой, 6 утра на часах, делаю до сих пор. Спустя 3 часа узнать что это нереально - здорово.

Comment: Это не тот львовский учебник, в котором стандарт языка заменен ссылками на Borland C++ for DOS?...